# Why it's occurring a error in .htaccess is it because of conditions in it?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

i'm working a small project in which i'm using .htaccess to make URLs short and sweet. But it's not working. Here's the code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php                   #removing .php extension


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ category.php?category=$1  #removing get variables
```

By using the first condition it's removing the use of .php extension in the URL bar. And the second condition is added with an intention to remove the GET variables. URL is something like this:

```
www.example.com/category.php?category=latest
```

and i want this url to be look like this:
www.example.com/category/latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip the order otherwise first rule will catch this category URI also.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ category.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.